# mac OS Mojave でXcode 8 は対応してないのでしょうか？

Tags: xcode

OSをMojave にアップグレードしてからXcode 8.3.3を起動しようとしたところ、

問題が起きたためXcodeを開けません
開発者にXcodeがこのバージョンのmac OSで動作する事を確認してください

というエラーが出てしまいます
mojaveは最新のXcodeしか対応してないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

すでに Чайка さんが書かれていることの補足ですが、AppleのDeveloper ForumsにもXcode 8がMojaveで動かないと言う報告が上がっています。

[Xcode 8 macOS Mojave](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106262)

主題が「Swift 2からSwift 3への移行のためにXcode 8を使いたい」と言うことでしたので、スレ長が延びていますが、「(MojaveでXcode8を動かすのは)あきらめろ」と言う意味以外のレスはついていません。

(本家英語版StackOverflowにもいくつか同内容の質問が見られましたが、意味のある回答は見つかりませんでした。)

また**App Storeへ登録するためのiOSアプリ開発には、Xcode 8は使えません**。

[Upcoming iOS 11 App Update Requirements](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05072018a)

既存iOSアプリの更新をApp Storeに登録する場合にも、Xcode 9/iOS 11 SDKでビルドすることが必要であることの告知。(2018/7/1より有効。)

[Build Your Apps for iOS 11 and iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02152018a)

新規iOS用アプリをApp Storeに登録する場合に、Xcode 9/iOS 11 SDKでビルドすることが必要であることの告知。(2018/4/1より有効。)

古いXcodeを使いたい理由がわからないのですが、Appleは時々バッサリと古いものを切り捨てることがあるため、新しいXcodeに早めに移行された方が良いでしょう。

---

ちなみに、MacのOSダウングレードはサポートされていませんので、導入したいmacOS(SieeraかHigh Sierra)のインストールイメージを入手した上で、「クリーンインストール」するしかないと思います。(それによって、Timemachine等のバックアップが読めなくなる可能性もあります。)ブート可能な外付けHDD/SDDを持っておられれば、そちらの方に古いmacOSをインストールできるかもしれません。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。「Xcode 10がMojaveで動かないと言う報告が上がっています」というのはXcode 8の間違いでしょうか？Xcode9以上じゃないと登録できない、という事ですよね？

Comment: @たかしたか さん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正しておきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり最新のXcodeで対応するしかないようですね。

Comment: @たかしたか さん、そうですね。ただ、Swift 2から3への移行はXcode 8.x搭載のmigratorを使わない限り非常に大変(使っても相当大変ですが…)なので、お手元のSwift 2コード資産が膨大な量であるのならば、中古市場を漁ってでも古いmacOS搭載Macを手に入れた方が良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8.3.3のリリース日が2017年6月ですが、その時の対応OSが10.12なので、10.14と2つもOSバージョンが違うと、サポート外は充分あり得ることだと思いますし、10.14の新機能への対応やSwiftのバージョンも上がっているため、Xcode 10が必須なのだとおもいます。

もし仮に、Swiftのバージョンが上がることを嫌ってのXcode 8から最新のXcodeへの乗り換えをためらっておられるのでしたら、これを機会に最新Swiftに開発中のコードを書き替えることをお勧めします。

逆に業務などでソースコードに安易に手を入れられないのであれば、開発用OSとXcodeは従来のまま、OS 10.14で動作を確認するためのマシン（またはパーティション）を用意した方がいいと思います。

追記

@たかしたか さん、とりあえずディスク全体のバックアップを取ってから、（ディスクの買い足し？）ディスクを完全初期化して、それから [mas](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas/releases/tag/v1.4.0) というコマンドラインツールで AppStoreから非公開になった 10.12 (Sierra)のインストーラーをプロダクトID指定でダウンロードできるかも知れませんね。 masは、TerminalのコマンドラインからAppStoreのアプリをダウンロードできるツールです（ただし、購入済みか無償のものしかダウンロード出来ないと思いますが）

Sierra, High SierraのプロダクトIDは、`mas` プロダクトID等でネット検索して確認して下さい。
変動しないとは思いますが、ややイレギュラーな方法なので、ここに直接それぞれのプロダクトIDを記載するのは控えておきます。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。ちなみにOSをmojave からSierraにダウングレードする方法はあるのでしょうか？リカバリーで以前のOS(Sierraより前のバージョン)に戻してSierraにアップグレードする、みたいな事はできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 既に@OOPerさんが説明して下さっていますが、インストール済みのOSに上書きインストールでバージョンが古いOSはインストール出来なかったように思います

Comment: [macOS High Sierraへのリンク](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT208969), [macOS Sierraへのリンク](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT208202)はそれぞれApple公式のリンクがあるので、特にコマンドラインツールとかなくても(条件さえ満たせば)インストールはできそうな気がします。